# How to draw a diagonal line with mark_rule that stretches to infinity in Altair

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I want to draw a diagonal line in Altair that goes on forever (e.g. an identity line where x=y).

I drew a line between two points (xmin, ymin) and (xmax, ymax) using `mark_rule`like this:

```
x1, x2 = alt.param(value=xmin), alt.param(value=xmax)
y1, y2 = alt.param(value=ymin), alt.param(value=ymax)
line = (
    alt.Chart()
    .mark_rule()
    .encode(
        x=alt.datum(x1, type="quantitative"),
        x2=alt.datum(x2, type="quantitative"),
        y=alt.datum(y1, type="quantitative"),
        y2=alt.datum(y2, type="quantitative"),
    )
    .add_params(x1, x2, y1, y2)
)
```

But the line is only drawn between these two points. I want the line to go on forever in both directions. Similar to a vertical or horizontal line. Is that possible? For example to draw a line from (-infinity, -infinity) to (+infinity, +infinity)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using `alt.value` you can anchor the line to a pixel value rather than a value of the data axis. So even if you zoom out and the axis extent change, the line will span the same pixel distance. You can either hardcode the heigth/width of the chart or use the special signals for this like so:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars.url

points = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
)

line_black = alt.Chart().mark_rule().encode(
    x=alt.value('width'),
    x2=alt.value(0),
    y2=alt.value(0),
    y=alt.value('height')
)

line_red = alt.Chart().mark_rule(color='red').encode(
    x=alt.value(0),
    x2=alt.value('width'),
    y=alt.value('height'),
    y2=alt.value(0)
)


(points + line_black + line_red).interactive()
```

[image]

Zoomed out:

[image]

The above would create the line x=y only if the x and y scale's domain spans the same range. If that is not the case (like for the data above), you have two options:

### 1. Manually change the scale domain to be the same

We can set the y=axis to have the same max as the xaxis:

```
points = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y=alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q').scale(domainMax=240),
)
```

[image]

### 2. Compute the lines as the ratio of the original domains

I'm not sure if there is a way to automatically find the max value of the y and x domain, but that would make this more robust (maybe look around in the Vega-Lite issue tracker or ask there). For now, I just plug in the values manually:

```py
line_black = alt.Chart().mark_rule().encode(
    x=alt.value(0),
    y=alt.value(0),
    x2=alt.value(alt.expr('width * 50/240')),
    y2=alt.value('height'),
)

line_red = alt.Chart().mark_rule(color='red').encode(
    x=alt.value(0),
    y=alt.value('height'),
    x2=alt.value(alt.expr('width * 50/240')),
    y2=alt.value(0),
)
```

[image]

---

It would be nice to have this in the docs, so feel free to add a PR to the rule page if you wish https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/rule.html#width-height-spanning-rules. Issue here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3317

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is definitely useful and I can add a PR about this. But in this case x != y because the line is now not anchored to the values on the axis anymore. What I would like is the same as in your example but specifying values on the axis. E.g. the line should go through (0,0) and (100,100) but going on forever in both directions. I am sorry if my question was not very clear.

Comment: @AntoniaH Sorry, my bad. I updated the question with a possible way to achieve x=y (as long as you keep the zoom for x and y linked and don't zoom one axis at a time (so keeping the default interactive behavior)

Comment: Thank you @joelostblom This will work as long as you do not move the data around inside the figure. Or it would have to recompute the line based on the new max value of the x and y domain if that is possible.

Comment: @AntoniaH Yes correct, you can zoom in and out but if you pan then the ratio will remain, but the actual values change. I don't know of a why to show an infinite line for x=y, but you could of course set it to a really large number using `alt.datum` and then set the domain to zoom into to the region of the data instead of the max value of the line. That might be the most practical for your application even if it is a bit more "manual"